# TapKey - Getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to view own locks via the API

Tags: tapkey

On the [TapKey Integrator Portal](https://portal.tapkey.io/portal) I have a Client Credentials OAuth client, which I created after logging into my owner account.

I can use this to successfully authenticate against *https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token* with the following scopes:

```
write:ip:users read:ip:users read:owneraccounts write:owneraccounts read:core:entities write:core:entities read:grants write:grants
```

However, when I try and call GET [https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Owners/{my-owner-id}/BoundLocks](https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Owners/%7Bmy-owner-id%7D/BoundLocks) using the bearer token returned from the *connect/token* endpoint, I am getting a 403 back.

The locks are owned by the same account I logged into the Integrator portal and created the OAuth client with.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to check in this case is, if the *Client Credentials client* has administrator rights to the owner account.

As you most likely know, this client acts as its own user and the user identified with an email address in format `{oauth_client_id}@iam.serviceaccount.tapkey.com` must be added as a co-administrator of the desired owner account.

The option to do this automatically is available when you are creating such OAuth client (as a checkbox), but can assigned manually later as well.

The reason for this not being done always automatically is, that the OAuth client doest not necesarrily need to manage the owner account it has been created in.

Comment: Aha! I was clearing out smartphone users and must have deleted the administrator user by accident  It could be useful to not have this listed alongside normal smartphone users 